# Children Navigation Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

everyone. 
I have and issue with @angular/router.
I have the routes config for my app.

```
Router [] = [
   {
      path: 'main',
      component: MainComponent,
      children: [
          {
             path: 'info',
             component: InfoComponent
          }
      ]
   }
```

And i have the next flow: i entry the page and it navigates to MainComponent, that just gain the object from DB. Inside MainComponent i use `this.router.navigate(['info'], {relativeTo: this.route})`.
In the InfoComponent i have componentResolver that depends on the parent from the MainComponent

```
export class InfoComponent extends OnInit {

    constructor (@Host() private parent: MainComponent) {}

    ...

    ngOnInit () { `componentResolver is done` }
}
```

The problem is, when I navigates back by the back button in the Chrome navbar, or clicking Alt+< , it shows me just empty view(MainComponent).
Where is my problem and why is this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this router configuration instead of doing the navigation yourself manually in the MainComponent (so remove `this.router.navigate(['info'], {relativeTo: this.route})` ):

```
Router [] = [
   {
      path: 'main',
      component: MainComponent,
      children: [
          { 
            path: '', 
            redirectTo: 'info', 
            pathMatch: 'full' 
          },
          {
             path: 'info',
             component: InfoComponent
          }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: This is just the same as calling `Router.navigate`

Comment: I have this configuration in one of my applications and I don't have the problem that the OP mentioned when navigating back.